# Shoul supporting documents for a Schengen visa be translated?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, translations

I'm planning on applying for a Schengen short-term visa. I have all documents required for the application? I'm applying via the Netherlands consulate? Do I have to translate things like bank statements, letter of employment, travel insurance, etc? Even if the form given at the consulate is in my local language (Spanish).

Answer (score 2):

I contacted the consulate again (well, not actually the consulate BUT the company that handles the documents reception, etc, VFS Global) to see if they could give me a definite answer. It turned out that the only documents that needed translations are official documents like birth/marriage/adoption certificates, etc. There was no need to provide any translations for the supporting documents. Hope this helps someone.