# Who can certify translations of supporting documents for (travel) Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, translations

If my original document is not in English, can I both translate it and verify that it is correct (with a confirmation letter)? The website of The British Embassy in Japan does not say that a translation must be certified by a translation agency. I'm not sure about Schengen countries.

Just in case, I'm talking about documents like pay slips or employment verification letter and not documents with serious legal consequences like birth certificates etc.

Comment: Which Schengen country(ies) are you applying to? Section 6.1.2 of https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page42 states “...consulates should inform applicants (e.g. on websites, on notice boards) which documents must be translated and into which language” As a general rule, it’s expected that any translations are produced independently by a source that the authorities can verify. See also related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101924/shoul-supporting-documents-for-a-schengen-visa-be-translated

Comment: Exactly which country are you trying to apply for a visa? First you mentioned a Schengen visa, but then you quoted something from a British embassy?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I am trying to apply for a visa in Germany. UK is just an example.